# does android allow one public class in another public class?

Tags: android

can someone help that how can i correct it!!!

```
package com.indoreencyclopedia;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class HistoryActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);

 /* here it shows to remove invalid modifier "Public"*/

public static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        private static String DB_PATH =         "/data/data/com.indoreencyclopedia/databases/";

        private static String DB_NAME = "MyLocation";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

        private final Context myContext;


        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }   

      /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own   database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }else{

                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                   //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                //database does't exist yet.

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        /**
         * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
         * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transfering bytestream.
         * */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        } 

}
}
}
```

Comment: just define `DataBaseHelper` in separate file and you'll dont have that problem

Comment: You can define nested classes. But not within the scope of a method. Move the declaration of DataBaseHelper out of the onCreate method scope. Of course it would even be nicer to move this class to a seperate file.

Comment: you can't define a public class in a method.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are missing a closing curly brace for the onCreate method. Or more correctly, your closing curly brace is at the bottom of the file instead of at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't care. But it's not possible due to the Java standard. Forget it and refactor your code. Put the Helper class in its own java file.

Comment: Please explain down-votes. I think that's technical correct. If it isn't please enlighten me.